# How to pass back data from parent component to child component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I'm using Google Place Autocomplete in my child component, but when each input is filling with data, the parent component does not get the change, so i can't post to server valid data.

I have a child component that I call in the parent component:

```js
<rc-billing-data *ngIf="accountData"
      [clientRegion]="accountData.region"
      [(currencyModel)]="accountData.currency"
      [currenciesModel]="accountData.currencies"
      [(billingLanguageModel)]="accountData.billingLanguage"
      [localeModel]="accountData.locales"
      [(autoPaymentModel)]="accountData.enableAutoPayment"
      [(countryModel)]="accountData.country"
      [billingCountriesModel]="accountData.billingCountries"
      [(zipModel)]="accountData.zip"
      [(cityModel)]="accountData.city"
      [(addressNameModel)]="accountData.addressName"
      [(addressTypeModel)]="accountData.addressType"
      [(addressNumberModel)]="accountData.addressNumber"
      [(addressFloorDoorModel)]="accountData.addressFloorDoor">
    </rc-billing-data>
```

In the child component the google place input calls handleAddressChange function:

```html
<label for="googleAddress">Pontos cím keresése</label>
        <input ngx-google-places-autocomplete
               (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"
               id="googleAddress"
               type="text">
```

The handleAddressChange function is changing the input's value, but the accountData does not updating.

```js
handleAddressChange(event) {
    let address: Address;
    this.zipModel = '';
    this.cityModel = '';
    this.addressNameModel = '';
    this.addressTypeModel = '';
    this.addressNumberModel = '';
    this.addressFloorDoorModel = '';

    this.addressCoordsModel = {
      lat: event.geometry.location.lat(),
      lng: event.geometry.location.lng()
    };

    address = this.regionHelper.setAddressParts(this.clientRegion, event.address_components);

    this.countryModel = address.country;
    this.zipModel = address.zip;
    this.cityModel = address.city;
    this.addressNameModel = address.addressName;
    this.addressTypeModel = address.addressType;
    this.addressNumberModel = address.addressNumber;
  }
```

If I typing manual into inputs those are working correctly.

Comment: Parents pass data to children with properties and children to parents with events. What ``ChangeDetectionStrategy`` are you using?

Comment: I'm using default strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to have an output event emiter in your child component (it would be better to have one input with all AccountData) and your parent object need to manage this event. For example:

**Parent need to have this**

**HTML**

```
<child-component [accountData]="accountDataObject" (changesOnChild)="parentDetectChanges(event)" > </child-component>
```

**ts**

```
parentDetectChanges(newData: any){
    //put the new values here


}
```

**child**

```
@Input() accountData: AccountData;
@Output() changesOnChild = new EventEmitter<AccountData>();

....
some code
....

handleAddressChange(event) {
    //modify account data object

    ...

    this.changesOnChild.emit(this.accountData)
}
```